# Convert XBMC Database Schema 4.0a in sqlite to mysql

Tags: mysql, sqlite, xbmc

I would like to use the database schema of Xbmc to my webapplication. 
You can see the schema here : http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Database_Schema_4.0/a

In my server, I have a mysql database, so I test to convert sqlite to mysql with firefox plugin :
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

I add the first table (2.1 Table: profile) No problem.
I add the seconde table (2.2 Table: collection) I have a syntax error with FOREIGN.

```
[ near "FOREIGN": syntax error ]Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILUREException Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

I don't know the good syntax for foreign key. Somebody can help me?

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) knows the syntax.

Comment: Thanks but why xbmc give code with syntax error? Is really sqlite ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with the schema generated via the firefox plugin.
You could try using [SQLite Professional](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sqlite-professional/id586001240?mt=12) to export your SQLite database to MySQL. Open your database in SQLite Professional, and choose Data -> Export -> MySQL. This will create a script that you can run on your MySQL database to populate it.

Here is a promo code to get a free copy of SQLite Professional: Y6E3M4H34APR